# Page missing code in "the head part", how to add back in Wordpress?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, internet-explorer-8

Newbie. Theme is not behaving in IE8. Checking out source code, noticed theme demo, which looks great in IE8, has this code at end of "the head part" and mine does not:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="//html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><link rel="stylesheet" id="themetastic_ie8" href="http://themetastic.damojothemes.com/wp-content/themes/themetastic/css/ie8.css" type="text/css" media="all"><![endif]--></head>
```

Crossing my fingers that's the problem. Do you think this looks like the culprit? If so, after I change the href to point to my ie8.css file, how would I get this code to work and added to all of my pages in WordPress?

Appreciate your insight.

Theme: http://themetastic.damojothemes.com/sidebar-left/
My site: www.thetrafficticketman.com/scott-markowitz

Comment: You have put it in `header.php`file only, not all theme pages!

Comment: You can ask wordpress questions at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you, that seems to work. Didn't know about the wordpress version of stackexchange. Will def. post there going forward. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can add that code to your theme's header.php file, in between the  and  tags. It may make a difference if you add it before/after the PHP function call wp_head();....so try out both and see what works best for you.

Comment: Thank you, that seemed to work like a charm. Appreciate your reply!